# How can I add several "instances" of a layout into another layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a layout `activity_main.xml` which contains this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</LinearLayout>
```

And I've a layout, new_bucket.xml which contains this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/newEntry"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#253514"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="toggleAmagar" 
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/child"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/main"
        android:background="#666666"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="toggleAmagar" 
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text2" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I want to achieve, is to programatically add several "instances" of `new_bucket.xml` to the main layout in activity_main.xml. Those instances, should appear inside the LinearLayout of `activity_main.xml`.

I'm a bit stuck at the moment. I've tried to just add a TextView to `activity_main.xml` but I can't even handle that...

```
LinearLayout my_root = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
LinearLayout A = new LinearLayout(this);
A.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("This text should appear somewhere");
A.addView(tv);
my_root.addView(A);
```

But that TextView is never shown.

Can you help me out?

Comment: u want multiple linear layout in ur my_root layout???

Comment: Yes. For example, 3 "times" `new_bucket.xml` into `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layout activity_main.xml
// i added an Id for LinearLayout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
             >
        </LinearLayout>
```

This code will add your new_bucket to your main LinearLayout

```
 LinearLayout my_root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container, null);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View bucket= (View) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_bucket, null);
    my_root.addView(bucket);
```

Hope this work for you.

Comment: Okay, this worked, but without that duplicate `android:id="@+id/linear_activity_main" >` line. I'm going to post the final answer with the code working.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.new_bucket, container);
container.addView(child);
```

See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Comment: It's still throwing a NullPointerException in `container.addView(child);`

Comment: Try to make another LinearLayout inside activity_main.xml with id = container. Also check if findViewById is returning null. And add LayoutInflater inflater; = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); to your onCreate.

Comment: `container` is returning Null. `(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);`

Comment: Did you put your setContentView() BEFORE the findViewById call? And you have to create that extra LinearLayout inside your activity_main.xml.

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);  
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.new_bucket, container, false);  
child.setId(0);  
container.addView(child);

if u want to inflate multiple layout use for loop for this.
```

Comment: Aswell as the previous answer, line `container.addView(child);` is throwing a NullPointerException

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater; = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

add this line to ur onCreate() method.

Comment: My code is: `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
  
  LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);  
  View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_bucket, container, false);  
  child.setId(0);  
  container.addView(child);` still crashing with same nullpointerexception.

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


Try to add another layout in ur activity_mail.xml & inflate with it id.

Comment: Did that. `activity_main.xml` first LinearLayout has id `android:id="@+id/mainActivity"` and the child from it has `android:id="@+id/container" ` but no matter which one I try to access, always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

After so many help from so nice guys, I managed to do that.

I have not changed any Layout from the main question.

BUT java code is like this now:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout my_root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View bucket= (View) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_bucket, null);
    my_root.addView(bucket);
}
```

Comment: Notice that setContentView MUST be before anything.